# List my YouTube playlists

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

On YouTube, I can create playlists.

Where can I browse the list of my playlists (see all the full playlist names at once, see the number of videos in each playlist at once)?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your profile picture on the top right, click on [YouTube Studio](https://studio.youtube.com/), then on the left on [Playlists](https://www.youtube.com/view_all_playlists).

This will take you to https://www.youtube.com/view_all_playlists